# Bootstrap datetimepicker showing two calendar months

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Here it looks like:
[image: Two months showing on click]

I want it to just show one month with it ranging the dates from the minDate to maxDate. And this works good but it is showing two views for some reason..

Here is the JS:

```
var maxDate = new Date();
var minDate = $("#from").val();
var datePickerLimits= $("#from, #to").datetimepicker({
  minDate: minDate,
  maxDate: maxDate,
  pickTime: false,
  onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
      var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
          instance = $(this).data("datetimepicker"),
          date = 
$.datetimepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || 
$.datetimepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
      dates.not(this).datetimepicker("option", option, date);
  }
});
```

Rails:

```
  = text_field_tag :from_js, l((params[:from].to_datetime or 
@item.date), format: :american_no_time), class: 'form-control 
input-sm datetimepicker', id:  'from'

 = text_field_tag :to_js, l((params[:to].to_datetime or 
@item.date_end), format: :american_no_time), class: 'form-control 
input-sm datetimepicker', id:  'to'
```

This is used with rails but it seems to be happening in the JS as the only thing that is being called is the class datetimepicker.

Comment: make a fiddle of your code or paste HTML here

Comment: Ok I modified the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **Startdate** and **EndDate** in date picker

```
var today = new Date();
var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

In your script add

```js
var today = new Date(); //Get today's date
var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0);  //To get the last date of today's month
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    startDate: today,
    endDate: lastDate
});
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything differently. And if you saw I am using datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the problem.

```
 var maxDate = new Date();
 var minDate = $("#from").val();
$(function () {
      $('#from').datetimepicker({
      minDate: minDate,
      maxDate: maxDate,
      pickTime: false
      });

      $('#to').datetimepicker({
      minDate: minDate,
      maxDate: maxDate,
      pickTime: false
      });
});
```